# NLTK - Install panlex_lite manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm new to NLTK, I downloaded most of the nltk packages with `nltk.download()`. But when I try install panlex_lite corpora it always get stuck. Then I downloaded the `panlex_lite.zip` file of size 2.2 GB from the internet. But I don't know how to get that downladed zip to the nltk datas and update the NLTK Downloader. I'm a Ubuntu 16.10 machine and the python version is 3.5. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several options here:

**Option 1**
With the following, similar to what you've tried

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('panlex_lite')
```

**Option 2**

Run the following command against python

```
python -m nltk.downloader panlex_lite
```

**Option 3**
Panalex itself can be found by visiting [this](http://dev.panlex.org/db/panlex_lite.zip) link, be careful its 2.1gb. Keep note of [this](http://www.nltk.org/data.html), which states that where the location that `nltk` will look for data, for example on unix its in `/usr/share/nltk_data` so if you download the data from another source other than `nltk` downloader, be sure to move it to the proper folder.

Comment: In option 3 is there a way to find that location.

Comment: As stated, the location is usr/share/nltk_data/ The bigger question is, what do you need panlex_lite for? I've refrained from downloading it because I've never needed it for anything.

Comment: @CharlesRajendran The location is wherever you've downloaded the file to.

Answer (score 0):

Try `earthy`:

```
pip install earthy
```

**TL;DR**:

```
from earthy.nltk_wrapper import download
path_to_nltk_data = '/home/yourusername/nltk_data/'
earthy.download('all', path_to_nltk_data) # Excludes the third party (non-NLTK) packages.
```

To download `panlex_lite` exclusively:

```
from earthy.nltk_wrapper import download
download('panlex_lite', path_to_nltk_data)
```

To download all third-party datasets not natively hosted on `nltk_data` github:

```
from earthy.nltk_wrapper import download
download('third_party', path_to_nltk_data')
```